# Firebird: sum of the multiplication of two fields within a select statement

Tags: sql, case, firebird, multiplication

Basically what I need is to get the sum of the multiplication of two fields.

For example: `SUM ((field_1 or field_2) * field_3)`

But `field_1` or `field_2` are selected based on the value of a fourth field, `field_4`

My table:

```
field_1: Float
field_2: Float
field_3: Float
field_4: Char
```

In short, what i need is something like this:

```
SELECT
...
IF field_4 = 'K'
THEN
    SUM( field_1 * field_3 )
ELSE
    SUM( field_2 * field_3 )
```

I tried with IF and CASE statements, but i can't make it work.
Here my real query:

```
SELECT  
    D.id,
    D.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.sale_unity = 'K' 
        THEN (D.cost_price * CI.quantity_k)
        ELSE (D.cost_price * CI.quantity_u) ) AS total_cost,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.sale_unity = 'K' 
        THEN (D.sale_price * CI.quantity_k)
        ELSE (D.sale_price * CI.quantity_u) ) AS net
FROM DETAIL D
INNER JOIN VOUCHER AS V ON V.id = D.voucher_id
WHERE V.client_id = 97 AND V.date BETWEEN '06/01/2012' AND '07/01/2012'
GROUP BY D.id, D.name
```

Comment: It does not work, first this error: `Token unknown - line 6, column 45
)` I correct this but still receive errors in `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what is wrong on your query is that your CASE statement is missing the END. Try this:

```
SELECT  
    D.id,
    D.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.sale_unity = 'K' 
        THEN (D.cost_price * CI.quantity_k)
        ELSE (D.cost_price * CI.quantity_u) END ) AS total_cost,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.sale_unity = 'K' 
        THEN (D.sale_price * CI.quantity_k)
        ELSE (D.sale_price * CI.quantity_u) END ) AS net
FROM DETAIL D
INNER JOIN VOUCHER AS V ON V.id = D.voucher_id
WHERE V.client_id = 97 AND V.date BETWEEN '06/01/2012' AND '07/01/2012'
GROUP BY D.id, D.name
```

Comment: Glad to help. And don't forget to accept the answer if it fits to you :)